# ¿Por qué el terminal no y el interprete de python no imprime los colores y en cambio muestra el codigo con la libreria colorama? Python

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, powershell

estoy aprendiendo python y he estado usando la libreria colorama, todo bien hasta que ejecuto el codigo en el powershell o cmd o desde el mismo interprete de pthon y no me muestra las cadenas en colores sino que sale el codigo. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!, ¿Has probado ultilizar la libreria "os"?
Utilizando import os puedes usar el comando: os.system("color np"), donde en este ejemplo "n" es un numero que cambia el color del fondo, mientras que "p" es una letra que te modifica el color de las letras.
color de fondo:
(0 : Negro)
(1 : azul)
(2 : verde)
(3 : aguamarina)
(4 : rojo)
(5 : purpura)
(6 : amarillo)
(7 : blanco)
(8 : gris)
(9 : azul oscuro)
Color de las Letras
(a : verde claro)
(b : aguamarillo claro)
(c : rojo claro)
(d : purpura claro)
(e : amarillo claro)
(f : blanco brillante)

Puedes combinar distintos colores de fondos con letras
Por Ejemplo:

```
os.system("color 0f") #fondo oscuro con letras brillantes
os.system("color 4f") #fondo rojo con letras brillantes
os.system("color 2e") #fondo verde claro con letras amarillas
```

No olvides colocar el "import os" como primera linea del programa.